# bash use a whitespace separator to store an array?

Tags: bash

I have a file with loads of from / to date strings taken from output of certificates files in the following format:

```
Jan 9 2015 Mar 2 2017
```

What would be the best way to split the string and store it in an array?

```
fromDate=Jan 9 2015
toDate=Mar 2 2017
```

Which I then want to apply the date command to

```
date $fromDate +%Y-%m-%d && date $toDate +%Y-%m-%d
```

Would I use 3rd whitespace as a separator or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no array involved.

You can read six things separated by whitespace, then group them together by doublequoting the variables:

```
#! /bin/bash
while read m1 d1 y1 m2 d2 y2 ; do
    date -d "$m1 $d1 $y1" +%Y-%m-%d
    date -d "$m2 $d2 $y2" +%Y-%m-%d 
done < <(echo Jan 9 2015 Mar 2 2017)
```

Replace the final `<(echo ...)` with the actual input.

Comment: Thanks! How could I get them to print on the same line?

Comment: to print them on the same line try: ``echo `date -d "$m1 $d1 $y1" +%Y-%m-%d` `date -d "$m2 $d2 $y2" +%Y-%m-%d` ``

Comment: Why not `read m1 d1 y1 m2 d2 y2 <<< 'Jan 9 2015 Mar 2 2017'` instead of `while read ...; do ... done < <(echo ...)`?

Comment: @BenjaminW.: Because the `<(echo ...)` is a placeholder of the input file which might contain more than one line.

Comment: Ah, I see "file" in the question now. Makes sense!